# Помогите оптимизировать sql-запрос

Tags: mysql, индексы

Данный запрос выполняется 16-20 секунд, что очень критично (должен не более секунды).

```
SELECT a.id,a.timeupdated
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.table2id=b.id 
WHERE b.table3id=1 && a.lasttime<a.timeupdated && a.deleted=0
ORDER BY a.timeupdated DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Таблицы вроде бы ничего особенного. В таблице `table1` 400K записей весом 107 МБ, в `table2` - 500 записей (96 КБ). Движок таблиц innoDB. В `table1` стоят индексы типа BTREE на `lasttime`, `timeupdated`, `deleted` (тип int, tinyint).

Собственно вопросы:

1. является ли движок innoDB правильным выбором для данного рода таблиц?
2. является ли вообще mySQL правильным выбором? В последнее время присматриваюсь к MariaDB, но пока не уверен, сильно ли производительности прибавится.
3. поможет ли более тонкая настройка индексов? В данном случае индексы устанавливались путем клика кнопки "индекс" напротив каждого из искомых полей.

Comment: А на `a.table2id` индекс есть? Должен быть...

Comment: да, тоже есть...

Comment: Еще не совсем понятно, зачем `LEFT JOIN .. b`, если в `WHERE` есть условие из этой таблицы: `b.table3id=1`. Может имеет смысл условие перенести в `JOIN`? `LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.table2id=b.id AND b.table3id=1`. Не думаю, что это решит проблему скорости, то облегчит задачу точно...

Comment: А вообще, имеет смысл `EXPLAIN` посмотреть...

Comment: 1) делаем `show create table` для каждой таблицы 2) делаем `explain select...` по вашему запросу 3) приводим эти данные в вопросе 4) можно ускорить запрос сделав inner join и перенеся `b.table3id=1` в условие `on` 5) можно попробовать ускорить запрос убрав join и сделав `where ... a.table2id in (select id from table2 where table3id = 1)`. Проблема скорее всего в сортировке 6) когда не используете innodb, всегда надо спрашивать себя - а почему я должен использовать что-то другое? Если не знаете ответа - используйте innodb (правда, я с MariaDB не работал)

Comment: 7) то, что есть индексы на lasttime, timeupdated, deleted не значит что они срабатывают. Будет лучше, если индексы объедините в один. Если такая выборка (с джойном table2) выполняется часто и должна быть быстрой, а выборка без table2 выполняется редко и может быть долго, возможно, имеет смысл добавить в индекс и table2id 8) а вообще мне че-то не сильно верится в то, что все так плохо. При таком количестве записей запрос должен быстро работать даже без индексов. Попробуйте сортировку убрать - работает быстро тогда? Может у вас просто памяти на сервере мало? Или сам сервер слабый

Comment: 9) профилировать запросы умеете? в консоли mysql делаем `set profiling =1`, затем выполняем несколько ваших запросов, потом делаем `show profiles`, выбираем один из запросов с большим временем и делаем `show profile for query ID_ЗАПРОСА`. Тогда покажет на что было потрачено много времени. Эту информацию также можно использовать для ускорения запроса. Сейчас, скорее всего, у вас основная часть идет на сортировку данных (без лимита сколько записей вернет?), но возможно и копирование во временные таблицы на диске. Надо показать что вас просят + профилирование, тогда можно будет сказать точнее